# DataTables columnFilter text-range search

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, datatables

Here is the code of columnFilter number-range filter:

```
   function fnCreateRangeInput(oTable) {

        //var currentFilter = oTable.fnSettings().aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch;
        th.html(_fnRangeLabelPart(0));
        var sFromId = oTable.attr("id") + '_range_from_' + i;
        var from = $('<input type="text" class="number_range_filter form-control" id="' + sFromId + '" rel="' + i + '"/>');
        th.append(from);
        th.append(_fnRangeLabelPart(1));
        var sToId = oTable.attr("id") + '_range_to_' + i;
        var to = $('<input type="text" class="number_range_filter form-control" id="' + sToId + '" rel="' + i + '"/>');
        th.append(to);
        th.append(_fnRangeLabelPart(2));
        th.wrapInner('<span class="filter_column filter_number_range form-control" />');
        var index = i;
        aiCustomSearch_Indexes.push(i);



        //------------start range filtering function


        /*  Custom filtering function which will filter data in column four between two values
        *   Author:     Allan Jardine, Modified by Jovan Popovic
        */
        //$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        oTable.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
            if (oTable.attr("id") != oSettings.sTableId)
                return true;
            // Try to handle missing nodes more gracefully
            if (document.getElementById(sFromId) == null)
                return true;
            var iMin = document.getElementById(sFromId).value * 1;
            var iMax = document.getElementById(sToId).value * 1;
            var iValue = aData[_fnColumnIndex(index)] == "-" ? 0 : aData[_fnColumnIndex(index)] * 1;
            if (iMin == "" && iMax == "") {
                return true;
            }
            else if (iMin == "" && iValue <= iMax) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (iMin <= iValue && "" == iMax) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (iMin <= iValue && iValue <= iMax) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );
        //------------end range filtering function



        $('#' + sFromId + ',#' + sToId, th).keyup(function () {

            var iMin = document.getElementById(sFromId).value * 1;
            var iMax = document.getElementById(sToId).value * 1;
            if (iMin != 0 && iMax != 0 && iMin > iMax)
                return;

            oTable.fnDraw();
            fnOnFiltered();
        });


    }
```

How could I edit it so that it would filter not number-range but text range? Like lets say doing in sql

> SELECT * FROM `animal` WHERE `BIRTH_CODE` BETWEEN 'BC-01-01' AND 'BC-06-29'

if user enters

> FROM: `BC-01-01` TO: `BC-06-29`

Answer (score 0):

Is the filtering being done on the server or the client?

If it's the client you want the filtering function to eventually get to something that you can sort properly. So if you want you could strip out the `BC` and the `-`s and parseInt the number... for example

```
var bcInt = parseInt(data.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
```

Then you'd need to go through each row and check to see if it matched the range you've given it... I think that should work. Basically you'd need to get integers and check them against your range. Also, that function won't be inclusive for the range so I've altered it in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/3k2t6dc6/) I created to illustrate what I mean.